# Sequelize Update, After Create Hook, and Literal Date

Tags: sequelize.js

In Sequelize, I have a Model `WorkFile` that has the following instance method

```
workfile.update({ path: '/path/to/here' }).then(result => {
  return result;
})
```

This works great except the `result` contains the following

```
{
  "created_at": "2017-03-02T16:32:42.542Z",
  "updated_at": {
    "val": "NOW()"
  },
  // etc
}
```

The update method worked, but the `updated_at` is still the db literal. **It only happens when I have an `afterCreate` hook in the Model.** I tried `workfile.get()`, `workfile.get({ plain: true })`. The only thing I managed to make work is to requery the database for the object which seems ridiculous. Is there a way to access the object without the literal updated_at?

---

**Edited**

Here's the hook:

```
afterCreate: function(workfile, options, cb) {
    return workfile.update({
            path: `path/with/${workfile.id}`
        })
        .then(wf => cb(null, workfile)) // <--workfile and wf both have literal updated_at
        .catch(err => cb(err)); 
}
```

Comment: What is the exact flow in this case? First is the `create`, then `afterCreate` hook and then the instance method? In which phase do you get the consoled result? And what happens in the hook?

Comment: @piotrbienias, just added the afterCreate hook. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Comment: your `afterCreate` hook is for a `branch` but you are just calling `workfile.update()` without a `WHERE` so it will update everything. The `NOW()` will be converted to a datetime once it is inserted, The `update()` function returns [`Promise.<Array.<affectedCount, affectedRows>>`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcount-affectedrows) not an `Instance`.

Comment: Sorry, just updated it again! It's the Workfile Model, and the afterCreate is on that model. I copy and pasted branch incorrectly! Thanks guys for keeping me straight

Comment: @doublesharp - Postgres

Answer (score 0):

For those coming in the future, in my model I was using `Sequelize.literal('NOW()')`. When I replaced that with `Sequelize.NOW`, the problem went away. Not exactly sure why, but it works as a fix!

Answer (score -1):

You are calling [`workfile.update()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcount-affectedrows) which returns an array of the number of changed rows in the 0 position and affected rows in the 1 position. You are looking at the `Model` not the `Instance` which is why you see "NOW()" - it will be converted to a Datetime in the DB and in each Instance.

In your `afterCreate` function you are accepting a `branch` Instance, and then on a the `workfile` Model you call `update()` without a `WHERE` so it will update *all* rows in the `workfile` Model's table. You also get an array back, not an Instance as mentioned above.

It's unclear if `branch` is a `workfile` or not, but if you want to change a property on that specific Instance/row you should use:

```
// change the "path" on the "branch" Instance after each create
afterCreate: function(instance) {
  // "instance" is an Instance of a "workfile" Model
  instance.path: `path/with/${instance.id}`;
  // call Instance.save() on the "instance" variable it after you set the property.
  return instance.save();
}
```

If you actually do want to update all of the `workfile`s regardless of what `branch` is you can use the following

```
// change the "path" on ALL "workfile" rows, displaying the results.
afterCreate: function() {
  return workfile.update({ path: `path/with/${workfile.id}` })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(`Updated ${result[0]} rows`);
    console.log('Affected rows:', result[1]);

    // since we are printing out the result here we also
    // need to return in in a Promise
    return Promise.resolve(result);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log("Error!", err));
}
```

You don't need to include the function arguments you aren't using, and by default Sequelize uses Promises so you can just return your `update()`/`save()` instead of using a callback.

Another option is to use a `VIRTUAL` field rather than storing this in the db since all you really need is the `ID`.

```
Sequelize.define('model', {
  path: {
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
    get: function getType() {
      return `path/with/${this.id}`;
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: Sorry, doublesharp. Branch was a misnomer. I've updated the question, as it is indeed an instance of the WorkFile model. Therefore the update is on an instance. I'm seeing some ideas here, though so I'll give them a try~

Comment: K, so I've switched to the save() syntax (my after create looks almost exactly like yours) and I still get the literal 'NOW' as a return value on the instance. Do you not get something like this?

Comment: Could you also include the `WorkFile` model definition in the question?

Comment: You have both your Model named `workfile` and the Instance named `workfile`... `Model.update()` is a thing but `Instance.update()` is not. Check out the first example.

Comment: If you want to get fancy, use a `transaction` as part of your create and then access it from `options.transaction` in the hook, that way you can back it all out if the update for the `path` column fails. This may not be necessary to store in the database though, you could use a `VIRTUAL` field to construct the `path`.

Comment: Am I wrong in saying instance.update is a thing: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#updating-saving-persisting-an-instance

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, but the format would be `instance.update({ path: 'new value' }).then(() => console.log(instance))`;